# problem in installing ansible on CentOS-8.5.2111-x86_64

Tags: ansible, centos, centos8

I need to install ansible on CentOS-8.5.2111-x86_64 but i have an error

```
[root@ansible3 ~]# yum install ansible
Last metadata expiration check: 0:01:56 ago on Wed 07 Dec 2022 02:42:20 PM EET.
Error:
 Problem: conflicting requests
  - nothing provides python3.9dist(ansible-core) needed by ansible-6.3.0-1.el8.noarch
  - nothing provides (python3.9dist(ansible-core) >= 2.13.3 with python3.9dist(ansible-core) < 2.14) needed by ansible-6.3.0-1.el8.noarch
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)
```

the steps i have done

1. first installed epel release by command [yum install -y epel-release]
2. then install python3 by `yum install python3`
3. and then trying to install ansible by the above command and the error is attached

Comment: Your question is [off-topic in StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). You have a better chance to get it answered if you move it to [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) or to [Superuser](https://superuser.com).

Comment: Please see the ansible tag description: `On-topic questions are concerned with the use of the tool itself (e.g. installing ansible and prerequisites, connection issues... are off-topic)`. That being said, [the only supported installation method is now through pip](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/installation_guide/intro_installation.html#installing-and-upgrading-ansible)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you execute command `python3`, what Python version does the prompt return?

Higher Ansible versions require Python3.9+. CentOS 8 is usually packed w a lower python version.

You can try to install it by locating where python3.9 is actually installed on the machine, and then install it via the pip3 module.

Try:

```bash
yum install python3-pip -y
python3 -m pip install ansible
```

It might install a lower version of Ansible.